# How will the function behave?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Let $x$ be a real number belonging to $[0,1]$. What will be the values of function $$f(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+{\big(\cos(n!\pi x)\big)}^{2m}$$ when $x$ is rational? What about when $x$ is irrational?

Comment: When you want to add formula write it between `$$` signs. like `$x$`, etc.

Comment: Also use `$\infty$`, `$\lim ...$` `$\cos(...)$` `$\pi$` commands.

Comment: I got the symbol literally... is that supposed to be $e\cdot x$ or $e^x$ (as in $\exp(x)$)?

Comment: Note that for $x$ rational $x=p/q$ there is such $n$ big enough (eg. $n>q$), that $n!x$ becomes integer. Then $(n!\pi x)$ becomes a multiple of $\pi$ and $\cos(n!\pi x)$ would become $\pm 1$. However, due to an irrational $e$ multiplier, the argument of cosine never becomes an integer multiple of $\pi$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$, so the cosine value is less than $1$ in absolute value, and $(2m)$-th power reduces it to zero as $m$ grows to infinity. Hence $f$ of rational parameter is one plus ZERO, that is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

After you modified a question I can give the answer: $f$ is one plus a [Dirichlet's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_function):
$$f(x) = 1 + I_Q(x)$$
which is a characteristic function of the set of rational numbers:
$$I_Q(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb Q \\
0 & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb Q
\end{cases}$$

So your function is $2$ for rational $x$, and $1$ for irrational $x$.

Comment: how did you characterise it as a dirichlet's function??

Comment: @prog_SAHIL See the reasoning in [my comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074325/how-will-the-function-behave/2077902?noredirect=1#comment4261339_2074325). Consider also reading the Wikipedia page I linked above.